# Add to cart not working after adding product dimensions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using **woo-commerce USPS shipping** plugin, after entering **product height, weight, length**

[image]

then go to frontend when I click on **add to cart** its showing HTTP ERROR 500  this page not working please check the screenshot
[image]

I have checked my permalinks, httaccess file, etc all is correct shipping setting as well I don't know why this error coming if I hit the refresh then its bring me back to the product page. please suggest me a possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to look at the logs of your application. Normally you can see what's behind your mistake 500. Without this information, it's impossible to guess

Comment: the error log showing everything fine not related any issue there related to cart